# In the steam summer sale 2017 once you change the sticker layout, can you change it back to normal?

Tags: steam

In the steam summer sale 2017 once you change the sticker layout, can you change it back to normal?

Answer (score 2):

I assume you ask how to restore the original position of the stickers on their page. You can go back to the original layout by removing the stickers and reapplying them.